# The method '[]' was called on null,/flutter ( 9972): Tried calling: []("id")

Tags: flutter, dart

need your help to solve this error together

the solution is that post a data from postman and when i print value.data get me the data in a map and that what i need , but when i send it to another class model git an error
here's the code and the error

first the data.vlaue

```
then((value) {
      // print(value.toString());
      print(value.data);
      print(value.data['status']);

      print('this is the value');
      ShopLoginModel.thisIsJson(value.data);

      emit(ShopPostSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(ShopPostErrorState(error.toString()));
      print(error.toString());
    });
```

2- the class model which have to send it the value.data

```
class ShopLoginModel {
  bool status;
  String message;
  UserData data;
  ShopLoginModel.thisIsJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? UserData.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }
}
```

3- and last here's the error

```
I/flutter ( 9972): {status: true, message: تم تسجيل الدخول بنجاح, data: {id: 5508, name: abdelrahman mohamed, email: abdelrahman_1@gmail.com, phone: 011359633, image: https://student.valuxapps.com/storage/uploads/users/Uh0BKroBp5_1635472870.jpeg, points: 0, credit: 0, token: CrNKyEOStSmxArUTWZ9mL5xvvl7geEqQAl3ZhBEl2TMXCEoxW6C5ELUUFbKy43SfLKSWIT}}
I/flutter ( 9972): true
I/flutter ( 9972): this is the value
I/flutter ( 9972): onChange -- ShopLoginCubit, Change { currentState: Instance of 'ShopPostLoadingState', nextState: Instance of 'ShopPostErrorState' }
I/flutter ( 9972): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9972): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9972): Tried calling: []("id")
```

need your help please <3

Comment: what is the user data class? Would you mind showing us the implementation of it?

Comment: The error message is clearly related to accessing a missing 'id' property, which you have not shown in your question.

Comment: UserData.fromJson(json['data']), the error is happening while converting the json['data'] to userData object, check the value received to that class it seems it is empty or null so the compiler couldn't read the id property